# How to remove Android/Trojan.Agent.gc infection?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, malware, antivirus

My local brand phone running KitKat is infected.I've tried various removal tools but of no use. Malwarebytes detects it in  `/system/app/FileExplorer.apk` but I am not able to uninstall it.

How can I remove it without root? I've tried factory reset and hard reset.

ROM : xolo_era_SO14_25092015,kernel: 3.10.16   Device : Xolo ERA

Comment: if it is in /sys, there is nothing you can do but flash a new ROM, Problem will be in getting a custom ROM or original stock ROM. Please edit your question to include the device model, in the hope some one can help

Comment: You have mentioned the ROM but not the device. Anyway here is the guide for rooting [Xolo Era 4k](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/how-to-root-xolo-era-4k-mt6735m-t3359690). If that is not your device, please search XDA on how to root it . But before doing that, search if Custom / stock ROM is available- else rooting will be a wasted exercise

Comment: @beeshyams Either OP confused `/sys` with `/system`, or you do (or both): `/system` is where the OS resides, while `/sys` is a virtual file system ([sysfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs)) created on boot. As for your second comment: OP didn't ask to root the device, but how to remove that Trojan *without root.* // It might well be a "[false positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positives_and_false_negatives#False_positive_error)" by Malwarebytes. Otherwise, if it really is a malware that managed it into the system area, re-flashing the stock ROM would be an option.

Comment: @Izzy: I assumed it meant /system. Thanks for clarification. Second comment was in-line with this understanding , given that he tried *various removal tools* and it infected the system partition. Thanks again

Comment: @beeshyams Yeah, I was irritated as well initially :) But still, as OP doesn't want to root, to me it seems re-flashing the stock ROM (of course downloaded from its official source, together with instructions and possible software to flash it) is the only way out that's left – provided it's really a Trojan, and not just a false alert. I've never heard of a malware placing itself into sysfs – which makes me think of either a false alert or a misspelling in the question :)

Comment: @Izzy @beeshyams Yes I Checked it is in `/System/app/filexplorer.apk`so what option is left.

Comment: @MuditKapil File Explorer? I doubt a real trojan would sit there. Try grabbing a second antivirus. See what it throws up.

Comment: @Dan B I tried Norton antivirus & Internet security,It results that device is safe.

Comment: I never trust any software that calls itself "anti ***virus***" for a system where no virus exists. Those apps are often causing more trouble than they're solving (incl. false positives and opening new vulnerabilities on the device – just check what permissions they want to become suspicious). No guarantees, but as I wrote before, it might well be such a "false positive". A Google search for ""android.trojan.gc" filexplorer" doesn't yield a single result. For "android.trojan.gc" there is a single result: this page here. Raises at least an eyebrow, right? ;)

Comment: @MuditKapil Izzy is right. Not only is Malwatebytes throwing a false-positive, and its questionable if antivirus apps are worth downloading in the first place.